# How does one enable and use SWARM demon & Whisper messaging functionality provided by Geth 1.5?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper, swarm

The release notes for Geth 1.5 states that:

> The Swarm daemon (bzzd) and associated helper tools are included and
>   somewhat functional. Whisper v5 PoC code is included in the
>   repository, but not enabled yet.

So how do you enable and use these features?

Answer (score 3):

To enable whisper just run Geth with the `--shh     Enable Whisper` flag i.e. `geth --shh`

To enable SWARM you need to Build Geth & Bzzd (Swarm Daemon) from source:

- go get -d github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
- go install github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth
- go install github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/**cmd/bzzd**

Then run `$GOPATH/bin/bzzd`. Note you need to supply the ethereum account used for swarm accounting as a parameter so this would be something like `./bzzd --bzzaccount=0x87_the_account_you_want_to_use_abc`

The [SWARM Guide](http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io) is a work in progress.